# Reporting Broken Theme event though upload was success

Tags: installation

I don't understand what is missing when the Install is reporting success, but the Themes page is reporting a Broken Theme. styles.css and functions.php included below.

Thank you, in advance, for your help!

When I installed the child theme, it seemed to find the parent.

```
Installing Theme from uploaded file: wp-velux-child.zip
Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

This theme requires a parent theme. Checking if it is installed…

The parent theme, Velux 1.1.3, is currently installed.

Theme installed successfully.
```

But the theme page is reporting the theme is broken

```
Broken Themes
The following themes are installed but incomplete.

Name    Description     
Velux Child The "velux" theme is not a valid parent theme.
```

styles.css:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Velux Child
 Theme URI:    https://github.com/djjonbrown/wp-velux-child
 Description:  Velux Child Theme
 Author:       Jonathan Brown
 Author URI:   https://github.com/djjonbrown/
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  velux
 Template:     velux
*/
```

functions.php

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'velux'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell Velux is a child theme of the Primer theme. I just made the same mistake... Velux is not a valid parent theme because it is a child theme!